# Error while executing java program with .sh file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, sh, executable-jar

I have error while executing java command with .sh file with external library.

I have wrote a script called executer.cmd which contains

```
java -cp .;hsql.jar hsqlconnector %*
```

its working fine with windows.

For Unix also I have wrote a script and make u+x with chmod but still m getting error
of

```
bash: hsql.jar command not found
```

My executor.sh looks like

```
java -cp .;hsql.jar hsqlconnector %*
```

Comment: try `./hsql.jar` instead of `hsql.jar`

Comment: still not working, permission denied error for hsql.jar

Comment: did you also "+x" hsql.jar?

Comment: yes i did +x for hsql.jar before getting that error, then got error for hsq.jar cannot execute binary file

Comment: I think I found the solution here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/526784/Linux-UNIX/cp-linux-include-additional-jar  

On Linux you must use `:` (colon) instead of `;` (semi-colon) to separate entries on a path - because ; has a different meaning in the shell on Linux.

Comment: Thnx it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you must use `:` (colon) instead of `;` (semi-colon) to separate entries on a path, because `;` has a different meaning in the shell on Linux.

See here:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/526784/Linux-UNIX/cp-linux-include-additional-jar